# Verify Business Identity

Tags: web-services, validation, business-logic

I'm developing a web application that involves businesses signing up. What is the best way to verify a businesses identity? How do I know the person signing up for "Pizza Hut" really works for Pizza Hut? Are there web services I can utilize?

Comment: Like a database that holds all employees of all businesses? Sounds highly unlikely...

Comment: How do you prove you *are* you?  While it appears flippant, take a moment to think about it...

Comment: Best way is to schedule a meeting with them, show up, and see how much effort they put into looking like a Pizza Hut.

Comment: You may not get many constructive answers to this question on Stack Overflow because the primary focus of this question does not concern a specific programming-related issue.

Comment: This question might fit better at http://answers.onstartups.com/

Comment: Don't be too hasty to dismiss this one.  All of the vendors I mentioned had APIs that did a scarily accurate job of establishing our identities and work history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it seems far-fetched, but there **are** identify verification services that can identify a person's identity. I've seen them in action and the info they had on me was downright scary. They knew where I had worked, where I went to school (even the one semester psychology class I took just for fun.)

These services work because they purchase public records.  For example, I took out a loan for an automobile at a bank, and had to list my employer.  That's how they know who I worked for from 1987-1994.

I would bet that these services could help you.

Here's one. (I'm in no way affiliated with them. We just had them demo their product to us.) http://www.idology.com/

Here is another:  http://www.veratad.com/fraud_prevention.html

We eventually went with services provided by Trans-Union (The credit reporting agency) in their IDMA and IDMV products. (I can't find the links right now - my PC is acting up, but you should be able to find them on the Trans-Union site.)

These services are not cheap, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. All valid points. I kind of figured this would be a manual process but wasn't sure if there was something I was over looking.