# Business Registration. A way to verify business is actually a business?

Tags: php, sql

Is there a way to verify that the business signing up is actually a place of business? I found a thread on Stackoverflow, [Verify Business Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221704/verify-business-identity), but it did not actually answer the question directly. So here is the issue and question.

A website allows businesses to register to their site. What can be done to verify that an actual place of business, that has employees, is signing up and not just some random person creating bogus accounts for non-existent companies?

Comment: Is the business US based or international?

Comment: This is not on topic for Stack Overflow and will vary vastly from country to country, sometimes even state to state, and it really depends on how you define "business".

Comment: If you are in the US, you could ask for the employer tax ID, but good luck getting that in most cases.

Comment: you are looking for something like dun and bradstreet which does have web services http://developer.dnb.com/

Comment: Business in this sense is one that is required to pay's taxes and report its earnings.

Comment: @Pekka웃   I am not sure how this is not a topic for Stack Overflow. I am wondering if there is a way to write code, to ensure that a place of business is actually signing up. I can see where you are coming from when you talk about different kinds of business's but none the less I am wondering if there was some code that I could use to verify this information.

Comment: Some helpful information on EINs: http://www.sba.gov/community/blogs/community-blogs/business-law-advisor/how-do-i-find-ein

Comment: @Nicarus  Thank you very much for the information and help. It is not that I am trying to be stupid but was honestly trying to see if there was indeed a way to verify this information.\

Comment: I never said nor implied you were "trying to be stupid"

Comment: @Nicarus   I guess the only way to verify this would be to have the place of business enter their EIN number whenever they signup?

Comment: @nicarus I know you were not. I apologize for making it seem that way.

Comment: @Nicarus you have helped me the most so far and I am very appreciative of that.

Comment: That is correct - they would need to provide their EIN for you to verify. Depending on *who* in the organization is filling out the sign up form they may or may not have it on hand.

Comment: Thank you for that. Is there a way to choose a best answer on this site?

Comment: I'll post a summarized version of may solution for you in a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could require/solicit from the company their EIN (Employer Identification Number). This is from the IRS, so it would only work for US-based companies. Some sole proprietors will not have one.

Here is a helpful source to get you started: http://www.sba.gov/community/blogs/community-blogs/business-law-advisor/how-do-i-find-ein

Comment: Thanks once more. I am very thankful for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to look for Business Verification Services like this one [`http://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/dnb/businessverificationoffice`](http://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/dnb/businessverificationoffice)